# Load hikashop framework in a external file?

Tags: joomla-3.x

I develop a small custom feature where i load images with ajax, my question is, how can i load hikashop framework and image tools in my external file?

I tried directly to load file from /com_hikashop/hikashop.php, but i this don't work.

Comment: You first need to import the Joomla API. Without this, the Hikashop framework won't work

Comment: I loaded already joomla api, in this file i have already i $db request and this work as well. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can initialize hikashop in this way:

```
    if (!defined('DS'))
    {
        define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
    }

    include_once rtrim(JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR, DS) . DS . 'components' . DS . 'com_hikashop' . DS . 'helpers' . DS . 'helper.php';
```